# In Android is it possible to force binder death?

Tags: android, android-binder

I have a Binder that I am sending to a remote process, that remote process uses `linkToDeath` to watch for when the Binder dies. The remote process gets the callback when the process crashes now, but is there a way I can trigger Binder death programmatically on the side that owns the Binder without crashing?